# How to split a dataset into 5 subsets of the same size?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, dataset, subset

is there a simple way to divide a dataset into 5 subsets of the same size? Also taking into account the percentage of class distribution?
It should be possible to access each subset directly.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Kfold? [scikit-learn StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) is a variation of KFold. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.

Comment: I would like to do a 5-fold cross validation with EarlyStopping. I would like to train a model 5times with EarlyStopping and each time the validation data set should be disjoint to the previous one. In this way I want to avoid that the model is indirectly learning the validation data. The whole thing should take place in a for loop.  I don't know now how I can take each of the individual folds when using StratifiedKFold in order to pass them as validation data.

Comment: Yes you can @CodeNow! Checkout this answer, where they explain how to work with the chunks created by the Kfold class. You can work individually with each chunk :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641547/5963546