# 'KFold' object is not iterable'

Tags: python

I have this error

> KFold object is not iterable.

Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(25, n_splits=5, shuffle=False)

print('{} {:^61} {}'.format('Iteration', 'Training set observations',
                            'Training set observations'))

for iteration, data in enumerate(kf, start=1):
    print('{:^9} {} {:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1]))
```

Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: By the way, can you put up some data

Comment: It is not supposed to work like that. You should use something like `enumerate(kf.split(sample)...` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641290/typeerror-kfold-object-is-not-iterable)